# Unable to create a CircularGuage in Python qt with qml using QQuickWidget on windows

Tags: python, qt, qml

I am trying to create a circular guage using Qml in Python as a QQuickWidget.
I am unable to do so as I receive the Error `CircularGauge.qml:18:9: NumberAnimation is not a type`

I am working on windows, where I have added `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qml` to my path.

I have copied CircularGauge.qml exactly as is from example found on the Qt site [doc.qt.io](https://doc.qt.io/QtQuickEnterpriseControls/qml-qtquick-enterprise-controls-circulargauge.html)

to solve this issue I tried adding `import QtQuick 2.0` to the CircularGauge.qml file, but then I receive the error `CircularGauge is instantiated recursively`

My python code is as follows:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView, QQuickWindow, QSGRendererInterface
from PySide6.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()

    QQuickWindow.setGraphicsApi(QSGRendererInterface.OpenGL)
    widget = QQuickWidget()
    widget.setSource('CircularGauge.qml')
    layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I have confirmed this works with other qml exampls,
for example if I replace `widget.setSource('CircularGauge.qml')` with `widget.setSource('view.qml')`

where view.qml is:

```
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
    id: main
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "green"

    Text {
        text: "Hello World"
        anchors.centerIn: main
    }
}
```

I get the desired result of a qml file loaded into a QQuickWidget

How can I load the CircularGauge in the same way?

Comment: Did you try adding `import QtQuick.Enterprise.Controls 1.3` to your `CircularGauge.qml` qml file?

Comment: so I tried that, but I received the error ```QtQuick.Enterprise.Controls" is not installed``` but it looks like QtQuickEnterprise.Controls was merged into QtQuick.Controls 1.4 after qt 5.7 [according to the qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/94457/module-qtquick-enterprise-controls-is-not-installed/4). importing so i tried importing ```QtQuick.Controls``` and then a receive the error ```CircularGauge is instantiated recursively``` again